# Find new coordinates of a point after rotation from center.

Tags: trigonometry

I am working on a project which is a auto part picker. I need to put all the parts inside the frame with correct coordinates. When the part is at 0, 90, 180, 270 and 360... count of 90. All the part will be a arranged inside the frame.

Now I have an issue regarding when the part is at bottom and rotate to an angle from center, it will become outside the frame. How to reposition the part according to per angle.

I tried with this [Link](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1223522781), but not working. Please let me know.

I have attached an image as well.

[Click here to see sample screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31mjo.gif)

Comment: The simplest way is to rotate the part, calculate the minimum and maximum $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the rotated parts, and adjust accordingly. Are you having trouble calculating these coordinates?

Comment: Your "sample screen" shows a rectangle rotated by 30 degrees, but in the question you say 0, 90, 180, 270, 360. Do you truly need to know what to do if the rotation is 30 degrees, or do you only need to know what to do for 0, 90, 180, 270, or 360 degrees? Also, is the rotated part always a rectangle?

Comment: I need to know the re-position of coordinates or new coordinates per angle

Answer (score 1):

If the rectangle is as tightly fit in the corner as in your drawing then this problem can not be solved with a single centre of rotation that serves every possible angle. You need to compose the rotation with some translation that may depend on the angle (or on the outcome of the first translation). Alternatively you could always use the same 'safe' translation but it may appear to waste corner space.

The following solution takes the second approach:
1. Compute the maximum distance M from the chosen centre of rotation (e.g., the centre of the rectangle) to any point of the figure.
2. Compute the horizontal distance H and the vertical distance V from the chosen centre of rotation to the edge of the frame.
3. If H < M, translate horizontally by M-H.
4. If V < M, translate vertically by M-V.

Comment: could you please provide any example of it.